# How do I use MAAS to deploy CentOS images?

Tags: maas

Can anyone point to the the right direction to deploy CentOS images with MAAS? I found a command to upload images but end to end deployment is quite obscure.

There seems to be a gap in the documentation and a short tutorial would be really nice.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I would share the answer I found, thanks to [this post on travnewmatic.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160413161710/http://www.travnewmatic.com/2015/02/ubuntu-maas-maas-image-builder-centos-6.html):

Once CentOS images are generated one should import them using the api after login:

```
maas root boot-resources create name=centos/centos6 title="CentOS-6" architecture=amd64/generic  content@=centos6-amd64-root-tgz
```

Builder script seems to be the way to go. Analyzing it, I tried to to use directly CentOS cloud images with populated curtin directory and virt-sysprep but with no success (installation of image doesn't complete correctly an MAAS node is stuck in deployment). I would need to spend more time to look at what is wrong with this approach as it would be more efficient.

Note that I recommend to modify the builder script and contrib kickstart configuration file to speed up image creation. Using kernel.org mirror lead to image creation failure... Instead, using near by mirror lead to image creation success with reasonable speed on homemade 32 GB RAM server.

Answer (score 1):

With MAAS 2.0, this is really easy: CentOS images are included in the stock configuration! Just go to the Images tab, choose the checkboxes by CentOS 6 and/or 7, and choose Apply Changes.

Note that MAAS 2.0 is the default MAAS stack in Ubuntu 16.04, but is still a release candidate (2.0 RC4) as of Aug 10th 2016.

If you are running a MAAS 2.0 RC and don't see these images as an option, make sure your image sync URL (in the Settings tab) is set to `https://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v2/daily/`. (The `.../release/` image source doesn't have CentOS images yet, but presumably will when 2.0 final is released).

Answer (score 0):

So the current MAAS version that loads as the default version under Ubuntu 16.04 is not MAAS version 2.1.3.

2.1.3 does include image support by default for Centos 6.6 and Centos 7.  I have tested Centos 6.6, and it works great, just be sure you have your ssh public key loaded first, and login using the user "centos" and your provate key that pairs with the above mentioned public key.

However when I test the Centos 7 image, I found that the Centos 7 network ports are disabled by default on first boot and must be enabled at the console during install (or by script, which is failing in MAAS 2.1.3), and the MAAS deploy scripts may need to be updated to resolve this.  There is no obvious way to turn the ethernet ports on, I can't even break in to see what's going wrong in the scripts.  So Centos 6.6 is what works now, as of 5/11/17.  I have another question open on the Centos 7 issue, so I will update that thread once I get a working Centos 7 running.